# attract attributes typing java plugin for rhapsody

Tags: java, plugins, rhapsody

I need to write a java plugin will draw on the attributes using the rhapsody . What do you recommend for that. Where should I start ? Previously I did not write plug-ins.

Comment: Asking for tool (plugin in this case) recommendations is off topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

First place to start is to look at the samples provided by IBM.  You can find them (on Windows 7, version 7.5.3 of Rhapsody) in:

C:\Users\\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\7.5.3\Samples\ExtensibilitySamples

There are 3 types you can create:
1.  A plugin (what you are asking about)
2.  A Check plugin (ties into the model check sub-system)
3.  Event callback plugin (don't know much about this one)

I've written 1 and 2.

There should be a how-to document in and around that directory area that walks you through creating a simple plugin.  If not, it probably is available in the Rhapsody help (from within the tool)

Basically, you write your Java plugin to conform to a specific interface that IBM provides(com.telelogic.rhapsody.core.RPUserPlugin), create a .hep file that describes the details of that, and then drop the .hep file into the .rpy folder of your project.  You then create a new profile in your model with the same name as your .hep file and that should link to the .hep information.

A sample .hep file looks like this:

```
[Helpers]
numberOfElements=1

#REM: Tranformer Generation plug-in
name1=Generate Transformers
JavaMainClass1=sida.jni.transformerplugin.TransformerPlugin
JavaClassPath1=..\TransformerPlugin\DefaultConfig
isPlugin1=1
isVisible1=1
DLLServerCompatible1=1
```

Take special note of the numbers added to the end of the attribute names:

ex. isPlugin1, isVisible1

You will want to match that to the name# attribute in the file.

Then make sure your java plugin class files are on the classpath or (better yet), co-located to your .rpy folder.  For example, our plugins sit in a folder right next to (at the same level as) our .rpy folder.

If all goes well, you should see an initialization string spit out in the Rhapsody console window for the plugin.

Hope this gets you started...